# Well order of power set of an empty set

Tags: order-theory, order-statistics

For an empty set $A$, can we infer that $\left \langle \mathcal{P}(A),\subseteq \right \rangle$ is a well order? In the exact definition of well-order, it says to choose non-empty subsets and find whether that contains a minimal element or not. How about in this case?

Comment: Your question does not match your title. You are **not** asking about the well-ordering of an empty set, you are asking about a well-ordering of a **singleton**.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Corrected!

Comment: You corrected nothing. Your title still says “well order of empty set”, and you are still asking about an ordering of a singleton.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is empty, then $\mathcal{P}(A)=\{\varnothing\}$ has exactly one element. The order you have is the unique order on the one element set, $\{(\varnothing,\varnothing)\}$, which is certainly a well order: every nonempty subset (namely, $\{\varnothing\}$) has a least element (namely, $\varnothing$).

It is also true that the empty set, together with the empty order, is a well-ordered set, since it satisfies the condition by vacuity.

---

Note: if $(P,\leq)$ is a partially ordered set, then an element $x\in P$ is **minimal** if and only if for all $y\in P$, $y\leq x\implies y=x$; that is, there is no element of $P$ strictly smaller than $x$. An element $x\in P$ is a **minimum** (or a least element) if $x\leq y$ for all $y\in P$. Different concepts.

A well ordered set is a (partially) ordered set in which every nonempty subset has a **least** element, not “a minimal element”. If the definition were “a minimal element”, then every finite partially ordered set would be well-ordered, even if it wasn’t *totally* ordered.

Comment: So basically, same approach would also yield that set $A$ which has cardinality one is also well-ordered, right?

Comment: @AnarRzayev: $\mathcal{P}(A)$ **is** a set of cardinality one. So... what are you talking about?

Comment: number of elements in $A$ is equal to one

Comment: @AnarRzayev: You said $A$ was empty, but your partially ordered set was $\mathcal{P}(A)$, not $A$. You are both confused and confusing.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I mean if you change empty set $A$ with some another set which has only element, then $\left \langle \mathcal{P}(A),\subseteq \right \rangle$ is a total ordering, right?

Comment: @AnarRzayev If you replace $A$ with a set with one element, then $\mathcal{P}(A)$ has two elements, $\varnothing$ and $A$, and *that* set is also well-ordered by inclusion, but that’s a different question. You really need to figure out what you **really** want to ask before you start posting.

Comment: My last question in comment was just extra question to you, main problem is on the forum one.